# In-App-Purchases PresentCodeRedemption get response

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

We have implemented the redemption of offer codes with RevenueCat using the function

```
Purchases.shared.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
```

As described in the RevenueCat [Documentation](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-subscription-offers#2-redeeming-an-offer-code) and the Apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3566726-presentcoderedemptionsheet). In our production App the Sheet is working as expected. It shows the redeem flow and the user can redeem the offer code, but then the App doesn't get the Response to unlock the Pro-Content for the App or for showing anything to the user.

How could we get a response from StoreKIT whether or not the Offer code did worked?

Comment: Where do you set up your payment queue transaction observer?  You should set it up in `didFinishLaunching`

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the payment observer in the `didFinishLaunching` Method in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Then you should receive a new purchase transaction on your observer when the offer code is successful